# Undefined Index error in PHP while adding data to Mysql database using a HTML(Php) Form

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have read all your Related Articles but didn't found my solution.
Actually I was creating a E-Commerce site and after creating Admin-Panel in My Project when I made a HTML(PHP) Form to add data to Mysql(database). the following error comes everytime.

"Notice: Undefined Index Error on a specific line in that Form"

[image: undefined index error in php]

My code is here

```html
<?php
include ("includes/db.php");
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
<form method="post" action="insert_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-date">

<table width="1200" align="center">
<tr>

<td> <h2> Insert a New Product</h2> </td>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" style="width:450px; height:30px; border:2px solid black;" placeholder="Enter Product Title" name="product_title"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 
<select style="width:450px; height:30px; border:2px solid black;" name="product_cart" >
<option> Select a Category</option>
<?php

$get_cats = "select * from categories";

$run_cats = mysqli_query ($con, $get_cats);

while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){ 

 $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];

 $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";

}

?>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <Select style="width:450px; height:30px; border:2px solid black;" name="product_brand">
<option> Select a Brand </option>
<?php

$get_brands = "select * from brands";

$run_brands = mysqli_query ($con, $get_brands);

while ($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){ 

 $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];

 $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title </option>";

}

?>



 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="file" style="width:450px; height:30px; border:2px solid blue;" name="product_img1"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="file" style="width:450px;  height:30px; border:2px solid blue;" name="product_img2"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="file" style="width:450px; height:30px; border:2px solid blue;" name="product_img3"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" style="width:450px; height:30px; border:2px solid blue;" placeholder="Enter Product Price" name="product_price"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" style="width:450px; height:30px; border:2px solid blue;" placeholder="Enter Product Descrption" name="product_desc"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" style="width:450px;  height:30px; border:2px solid blue;" placeholder="Enter Product Keywords" name="product_product_keywords"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="submit" style="width:452px; height:30px; border:2px solid blue;" name="insert_product" value="Add Product"> </td>
</tr>

</form>







<?php

if (isset ($_POST['insert_product'])) {



//for text adding we can use following code
$product_title= $_POST ['product_title'];
$product_cat= $_POST ['product_cat'];
$product_brand= $_POST ['product_brand'];
$product_desc= $_POST ['product_desc'];
$product_price= $_POST ['product_price'];
$status= 'on';
$product_keywords= $_POST ['product_keywords'];

//for images we have to use following code

$product_img1= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['name'];
$product_img2= $_FILES ['product_img2'] ['name'];
$product_img3=$_FILES ['product_img3'] ['name'];

//for images temporary names
$temp_img1= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img2= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img3= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];



if($product_title=='' OR $product_cat=='' OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_desc=='' OR $product_price=='' OR $product_keywords=='' OR $product_img1=='') {
 
 echo  "<script> alert ('Please fill all the Fields') </script>";
 exit(); 
}

$insert_product = "insert into products () value ()"; 
}
?>

<style>
body {background-color: grey;}



#form {
 
 position:absolute;
 left: 10%;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>

<?php


 if(isset($_POST['insert_product'])){


//for text adding we can use following code
$product_title=$_POST ['product_title'];
$product_cat=$_POST ['product_cat'];
$product_brand=$_POST ['product_brand'];
$product_desc=$_POST ['product_desc'];
$product_price=$_POST ['product_price'];
$status='on';
$product_keywords=$_POST ['product_keywords'];

//for images we have to use following code

$product_img1= $_files ['product_img1'] ['name'];
$product_img2= $_files ['product_img2'] ['name'];
$product_img3=$_files ['product_img3'] ['name'];

//for images temporary names
$temp_img1= $_files ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img2= $_files ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img3= $_files ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];



if($product_title=='' OR $product_cat=='' OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_desc=='' OR $product_price=='' OR $product_keywords=='' OR $product_img1=='') {
 
 echo  "<script> alert('Please fill all the Fields') </script>";
 exit(); 
}

else {
move_uploaded_file ($temp_name1,"product_images/$product_img1");
move_uploaded_file ($temp_name2,"product_images/$product_img2");
move_uploaded_file ($temp_name3,"product_images/$product_img3");

$insert_product = "insert into products (cat_id, brand_id, date, product_title, product_img1, product_img2, product_img3, product_desc, product_price, status) value (
'$product_cat','$product_brand','NOW()','$product_title','$product_img1','$product_img2','$product_img3','$product_desc','$product_price','$status')";

$run_product = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

if ($run_product){ 

echo "<script> alert('Product Added Successfuly')</script>";

}
}    
}   
   
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Just few minor fixes need to be done.

Like the **$files** you used should be in CAPS like

```
$product_img1= $_FILES  ['product_img1'] ['name'];
$product_img2= $_FILES  ['product_img2'] ['name'];
$product_img3=$_FILES   ['product_img3'] ['name'];

//for images temporary names
$temp_img1= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img2= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img3= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
```

*Well I didn't highlight this change because one of the answers already contains that part.*

After All, I don't think that your issue relies in your code blocks. Have you checked the settings of **PHP Version**.

Often most of the issues rise when you are not using the correct version of the **PHP.**

Hope That Helps. :)

Comment: Yes I was using Xamp with Php 7.0 and many old functions were not working in New Xamp.

Comment: I still can't understand the reason of down vote I got. :(

Comment: Please, read [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for understanding why your answer is down voted. "Just few minor fixes need to be done" is not enough and requires more details. Could you add hint of improvements for this code?

Answer (score 0):

The related articles point to something you've already done in your code, more exactly checking with isset() before doing anything with a variable. But I guess you overlooked a crucial aspect when you dealt with $_FILES superglobal (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php): variables are always case-sensitive in PHP, unlike functions.

```
$product_img1= $_files  ['product_img1'] ['name'];
$product_img2= $_files  ['product_img2'] ['name'];
$product_img3=$_files   ['product_img3'] ['name'];

//for images temporary names
$temp_img1= $_files ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img2= $_files ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img3= $_files ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
```

Should be:

```
$product_img1= $_FILES  ['product_img1'] ['name'];
$product_img2= $_FILES  ['product_img2'] ['name'];
$product_img3=$_FILES   ['product_img3'] ['name'];

//for images temporary names
$temp_img1= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img2= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
$temp_img3= $_FILES ['product_img1'] ['temp_name'];
```

In fact, I think these are the lines that the undefined index notices point to. Hope it works.

Comment: Let me check this issue and will return back to you

Comment: $_FILES also not working in my case. still the Error is same

Comment: Just had a look again, and saw you're using isset() only for $_POST['insert_product'] and that's obsolete now. Have you tried checking with isset() $_FILES  ['product_img1'] ['name'] for instance? Try adding if (isset(...)) conditional before you try working with any superglobals, and see if it works. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

try changing  enctype="multipart/form-date" to enctype="multipart/form-data"